# Groups with the same amount

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

> Let there be an array of digits $ [0,0,1,1,2,2,\ldots,9,9] $, how many ways to split this array into two subarrays, so that the sum of numbers in the subarrays is different by a multiple of $11$?

This problem has arisen through the solution of some other problem, so I do not cite my attempts at solution. I will be glad to any help.

P.S. If it is difficult to calculate manually, then I will be glad to see an effective algorithm.

Comment: First of all, note that if $A > B$ are the sums of the elements of the two subarrays, then $A+B = 90$ and $A-B = 11k$  for some $k$. Subtracting, we get $2B = 90 - 11k$, so $k$ better be even i.e. $k = 0,2,...$. Thus, $B$ can be equal to $45,34,23,12,1$. So you are reduced to the question : how many subarrays have sum $45,34,23,12$ or $1$. This seems easier  than the given problem.

Comment: Also, if you get a subarray with no $0$, you can adjoin one or two zeros without changing the sum, so you can eliminate the two zeros, and multiply the answer by $3$.

Comment: Does order matter here? I.e. is $[1], [0,0,1,2,2,\ldots,9,9]$ the same as $[0,0,1,2,2,\ldots,9,9],[1]$, or are those two different splits? Also, most of the time when I encounter the word "array", the order of the entries _within_ the array matters. Is that the case here?

Comment: Order is important.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that we have eliminated the $0'$s, in line with my comment. 
Following up астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг's observation, I think a good way to approach it is to figure out all the subarrays that sum to $11$.  Then we successively compute the subarrays that sum to $1$, $12$, $23$ etc.  We know that there is only subarray that sums to $1$.  We can adjoin any of the subarrays that sum to $11$, unless that results in a subarray with more than $2\ 1'$s, to generate the subarray that sum to $12,$ and so on.

I can't see a way to compute the number without constructing the subarrays.